# Is this error due to type mismatch? How can I avoid this in the future?

Tags: java

for this question:

> Given a non-empty string and an int N, return the string made starting
> with char 0, and then every Nth char of the string. So if N is 3, use
> char 0, 3, 6, ... and so on. N is 1 or more.
>
> everyNth("Miracle", 2) → "Mrce"
>
> everyNth("abcdefg", 2) → "aceg"
>
> everyNth("abcdefg", 3) → "adg"

I get a "Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to String" when trying the following:

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
  
  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i = i +n) {
  return str.charAt(i);
 }
}
```

However, if I use this:

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
  String result = "";
  
  // Look at every nth char
  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i = i + n) {
    result = result + str.charAt(i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

then the results are fine.

Is this error because I was trying to return an int when the question is originally in String?

How can I avoid this in the future?

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A char and a String are different types. Your second solution is correct. It is defined as String and it returns a String. Your first solution is wrong in two ways: it returns a char when a String is expected, and it puts a return statement in a for loop. You can only return once from a function, so the for loop is useless in that function.

Comment: Thanks! 

So if the question starts with: public String, then my final result needs to return a string?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a type mismatch

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
```

says that your method returns type String, but

```
return str.charAt(i);
```

is actually returning a character.

you can change that line to

```
return Character.toString(str.charAt(i));
```

or

```
return String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.charAt(i)` returns a `char`. This is not the same as a `String`, which is why the compiler complains about type mismatch.

You could use `String.valueOf(theChar)` to convert it.

Or you could use `str.substring(i, i+1)` to get a String (with just a single character) instead of a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

This loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i = i +n) {
    return str.charAt(i);
}
```

returns the first char of the string, because the loop terminates (due to the `return`) on **the first iteration**, but the method is declared to return `String` (not `char`).

Incidentally, you can solve the whole task in one line:

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
    return str.replaceAll("(?:.{" + --n + "}(.))|.*", "$1");
}
```